# Adding AD groups using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to write a script to add a group to an OU, I've stripped out the script and am using the command line to find the error and it looks like -path is incorrect, how do I use powershell to create a group in the specific OU without using -path.

**Command**

> New-ADGroup -name _AB_Read -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global
>   -Path OU=TEST,OU=NEW_Groups,DC=Corp1,DC=net

**Error**

> New-ADGroup : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type
>   'System.String' required by parameter 'Path'. Specified method is not
>   supported.
>
> At line:1 char:77
>
> - New-ADGroup -name _PL_Read -GroupCategory Security -GroupScope Global -Path OU=V ...
> - ~~~~
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-ADGroup], ParameterBindingException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.NewADGroup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your -Path should look like this **-path "OU=TEST,OU=NEW_Groups,DC=Corp1,DC=net".** You need **"** enclosing your path.

Without quotes, it will fail.

So, a new AD group in your desired OU should look like this

```
New-ADGroup -GroupCategory:"Security" -GroupScope:"Global" -Name:"test1" -Path:"OU=TestOU,DC=Contoso,DC=local" -SamAccountName:"test1" -Server:"dc.contoso.local"
```

Comment: Good catch.  One note:  you should use single quotes when you don't need to evaluate an expression, saves a few cycles compared to double quotes which force evaluation of the expression.

Comment: Cool! Good to know. Every cycle saved is a win in my book. Yeah, my AD powershell knowledge is from using Poweshell history in AD Admin Center. It always shows double quotes so that is what I do.

Comment: Thats a good one, worked perfect, and thanks for the tip!